# Android Firebase two nodes updateChildren, failed: DatabaseError: Invalid token in path

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a new Data into Firebase and update it on user, but I always get an error when trying to make the relationship. I've attached an image of the nodes and some code.
[image]

and the code :

```
        // Create a reference that point to transportador and the currenUser
    DatabaseReference wayPointRef;
    // Create a reference to the vehicle node db
    final DatabaseReference refVehicle = mDatabase.getReference("vehiculo");
    // Create a reference to the transportador node db
    final DatabaseReference refTrans = mDatabase.getReference("transportador");
    // Take the key create of the new vehicle
    final String key = refVehicle.push().getKey();
    // Show the key
    KLog.a("key of the new vehicle : " + key);

    mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sweetAlertDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(actvty, SweetAlertDialog.PROGRESS_TYPE);
            sweetAlertDialog.getProgressHelper()
                    .setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#00C800"));
            sweetAlertDialog.setTitleText("xxxxxxx");
            sweetAlertDialog.setContentText("Creando Vehiculo");
            sweetAlertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            sweetAlertDialog.show();
        }
    });
    wayPointRef = refTrans.child(currentUserKey).child("vehiculos");
    vehicle = new Vehiculo(key, vehiculo, carroceria, placa, modelo, pesoMax, volumen, largo,
            alto, ancho);
    Map<String, Object> vehicleValues = vehicle.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put(refVehicle + "/" + key, vehicleValues);
    childUpdates.put("/" + "vehiculos/" + key, vehicleValues);
    //mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);

    final String finalCurrentUserKey = currentUserKey;
    wayPointRef.updateChildren(childUpdates, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(final DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
            if (databaseError != null){
```

This is log answer :

> 06-08 21:09:56.794 7671-9043/xxxxxxxxxx W/RepoOperation:
>   updateChildren at
>   /transportador/lONs9g5nLON1Ql4Fs24REuz8T2z2/vehiculos failed:
>   DatabaseError: Invalid token in path 06-08 21:09:56.854
>   7671-7671/xxxxxxxxxxxx A/TAG: [ (FirebaseServiceManagerT.java:277)#run
>   ] 
>                                                              Param[0] = createVehicle:failed
>                                                              Param[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bVDb.png) = -999

Answer (score 1):

What most likely is happening is your keys contain some characters that Firebase doesn't allow you to have in your node keys.

Namely:

- . (period)
- $ (dollar sign)
- [ (left square bracket)
- ] (right square bracket)
- # (hash or pound sign)
- / (forward slash)

A simple `String.replace()` should work here.

Comment: I already solved, using updatechildren, thanks for your answer!